# Showing numbers without scientific notation in R

Tags: r, format

I need to show the following table in Markdown:

```
resumen<-data.frame(dato=c('cant_cli','debit', 'costo_real', 
                           'comis_max', 'pagos', 'comis_real', 
                           'recupero%'), 
                    valor=
                      c(nrow(ops), sum(ops$Debit),sum(ops$costo_real),
                        sum(ops$comision_max), sum(ops$Amount), sum(ops$comision_ganada),
                        sum(ops$Amount)/sum(ops$Debit)
                      ))
```

The result is:

```
        dato        valor
1   cant_cli 6.217400e+04
2      debit 3.943952e+06
3 costo_real 2.641091e+04
4  comis_max 1.021484e+05
5      pagos 2.003838e+06
6 comis_real 5.189941e+04
7  recupero% 5.080788e-01
```

But I need to have the following format:

```
dato           valor
cant_cli       62174   
debit        3943952   
costo_real     26411   
comis_max     102148   
pagos        2003838   
comis_real     51899   
recupero%     50.80%
```

How can I make the code use this format?

Comment: I assume you wanted `valor` column to be `numeric`.  But, in the last row, `50.80%` could convert the column to `character`.  Is that what you wanted? `c(as.character(round(resumen$valor[-nrow(resumen)])), paste0(round(100*resumen$valor[nrow(resumen)],2), "%"))#[1] "62174"   "3943952" "26411"   "102148"  "2003838" "51899"   "50.81%"`

Comment: `options(scipen = 999)` to turn off scientific notation

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
as.numeric(resumen[,2])
```

Comment: This was very mean of you David Arenburg!

Comment: What was mean about it?  David simply improved the formatting of your answer.  If you're referring to the down-vote, that was me.